# Inner Pages Redirecting To XAMPP Page

Tags: redirect, xampp

I have created a website in localhost.

Now when I click any of the inner pages in my website,it is automatically redirecting to XAMPP page.

I think there is somecode I have changed in my local server.But now I dont know what to change to get back to the my inner pages instead of XAMPP.

I am waiting for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I resolved it by navigating to \xampp\htdocs\index.php and modifying this line:

header('Location: '.$uri.'/xampp/');

to

header('Location: '.$uri.'/');

But that creates another issue: now when I open localhost I get "This webpage has a redirect loop". That can be solved by editing the DocumentRoot value in \xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf. For me it was C:/xampp/htdocs/joomla/jupgrade